# Eclipse: saving without save actions

Tags: java, eclipse

This one is hopefully easy:

I seem to remember there being a keyboard shortcut or menu modifier key for saving a file while temporarily deactivating save actions. I can't find info about this option anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure such a shortcut exist by default.

The default key bindings in place for the Save commands don't mention any special shortcut for avoiding the "save actions".

[image]

Comment: darn, and I thought I had an easy question for once. Thanks, by the way. (+1)

Comment: "There is no answer" is apparently the answer I get and I'll have to accept that, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

There is a work around, right after you save the file, type Ctrl+Z (undo) and it will undo only the save actions, while the file will remain in 'saved' state.

Comment: These days I have abandoned Eclipse altogether (using IntelliJ Idea), but thanks anyway for your answer