# How to use default values with Lombok and Eclipse save actions

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I use Eclipse Save actions, and generally find them very useful.  However, I've hit a scenario when using Lombok that is enfuriating.

In the following class, I want to set a default value for a field to prevent nulls, whilst still allowing a setter.

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    @NonNull
    private String value = "myDefaultValue";
}
```

This is great, until I hit save, when Eclipse makes the field final!  I generally don't want' to disable save actions, as I like what they are doing most of the time.  Just not in this instance!

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707303/eclipse-saving-without-save-actions) suggests that I can't save without running save actions, and it's a pain to keep enabling/disabling save actions whilst editing the file.

Comment: No way around this. You can have save actions on a per project though - so maybe that can help you out...

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, and has been fixed in [Issue 263](http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=263). Originally, this fix was delivered in Lombok 0.10.4, but as a side effect a new problem was introduced that has been addressed in the 0.10.8 release.

Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Lombok answer, I’m afraid. But in my experience `final` does more harm than good. It does not stop you from changing the object the reference points to (except, of course, for the immutable `String`). Optimization only helps little. I avoid `final` in Java, but like `const` in C++.

You can edit your Save actions and exlude adding the `final` keywords while still performing the other actions.